# How does `page-break-before` CSS property work?

Tags: php, css, page-break, dompdf

According to [DOMPDF's FAQ](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/faq.php#page_break), you can use `page-break-before` and the similar to force page breaks.

I had to lay out my page with tables, as DOMPDF [does not support floats](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=19).

On a `<tr>` element, I have placed `style="page-break-before: always"` but the generated PDF doesn't seem to follow this rule.

Is it because I have placed it on a `tr` element, and not a traditional block element?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @reiso What? What about sending PDF documents to people for printing you can rely on?

Comment: You've printed HTML and something unreliable happened?

Comment: @reiso Well there is no easy way to remove the text in the margins

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up solving it by

- closing the table I was in
- adding a         `<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>`
- reopening the table

Comment: I have no way to test at the moment, but it's possible that you could achieve the same result by using multiple `<tbody>` elements, rather than explicitly 'breaking' the one table across multiple tables.

Comment: late answer and maybe not relevant but today i fixed this problem with a div inside a <td> element of the row where i want to break the table